# Android - How to get file extension?

Tags: java, android, string, file

I have a String which contains path to the some file, for ex. "`/sdcard0/Lewis/cache.obb`".

How I can get file extension (w/out dot) from that String?

Note: file extension can be different, for ex. "`.tar.gz`".

Comment: The file extension of `some-file.tar.gz` is `.gz` by the way.

Comment: But I need to get all the ".tar.gz"

Comment: You will need to customize your logic.

Comment: If you're just working with Strings and can be sure that no dot will be in the path, you can use `String extension = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("."));`.

Comment: Otherwise when you're working with filechooser this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/53869269/3894304

Answer (score 5):

If you have the file path/URL, you can use `MimeTypeMap#getMimeTypeFromExtension()` like this:

```
public static String getFileType(String url)
{
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

And then you just call it like this:

```
String fileType = YourClass.getFileType(file);
```

Comment: Does it works with files named like this "`photo.birthday.my.son.jpg`"?

Comment: @user2718135 I haven't tested this code, try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
if (fileName != null) {
    File imageFile = new File(fileName);

```
String fileType=fileName.substring(imageFile.getName().length(),fileName.length());
```

}